# Relationships on mvc3 entity code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My project has two objects: users and meetings

Every meeting has one user that is the "head" of the meeting and a many users that are simple.

My models are these:

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public Location From { get; set; }
    public Location To { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public float Lat { get; set; }
    public float Long { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller for the meeting model. Now every time that i add another meeting a and in the user field i put an existing userid this user is not inserted and new user is created.

What's wrong?

**edit**
the create controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Tremp tremp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tremps.Add(tremp);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(tremp);
    }
```

in the form i just enter the id of the user

Comment: Can you show your controller post action where you create the new meeting?

Comment: How are you assigning the user? Any users you assign to the User property have to be retrieved from the Context, not from a new() instance. IOW, you have to load the User first, assign it to the meeting then save the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on EF code first, but your code example did cause some deja vu for me. I think the problem is that you need to configure the relationship between the "head" user and the meeting e.g.

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Column(name: "UserId")]
    public int HeaderUserId { get; set; }

    public Location From { get; set; }
    public Location To { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `tremp` entity has a reference to an existing user (`tremp.User`) you must attach this user to the context before you add the `tremp`. This tells EF that this user is existing in the database and avoids to insert a new user:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Tremp tremp)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Attach(tremp.User);
        db.Tremps.Add(tremp);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(tremp);
}
```